# Cannot start node server with forever using cron

Tags: node.js, cron, forever

In the `crontab` of my user I have the following:

```
@reboot /full/path/to/rebootcron.sh
```

`rebootcron.sh` is `-rwxrwxr-x`, I can execute it from the terminal and cron executes it also.

It has the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /full/path/to/directory
/usr/bin/forever start /full/path/to/directory/server-main.js
```

Executing it in the terminal starts the `forever` process as expected, but when cron executes it, the forever process stops with `Error: Cannot find module 'X'` where 'X' seems to be any module not installed locally in the `node_modules` directory where `server-main.js` can be found (these modules are installed globally, that is why I can start the forever process from the terminal). Why does the same user run the same script with a different environment, depending on whether I execute it from the terminal or I execute it through `cron`?

Comment: Install modules globally on server. :)

Comment: They are, that is how I can start the server from the terminal. The problem seems to be that when I run it from cron, it cannot find the global modules.

Comment: Check $PATH variable for node modules. Terminal is bash while cron is sh. Alternatively make a bash script to start the node server and put that in cron. remember to add `!#/bin/bash` at start of file

Comment: As you can see in the question, I start it from a bash script with `!#/bin/bash`, so it runs in bash already. My $PATH has nothing related to node in it, so I don't see how that could be wrong in cron.